# Mockito 1.9: format the expected value (like "actual formatter" in custom ArgumentMatcher)

Tags: java, formatting, mockito, powermock, matcher

In Mockito 1.9.5 I'd like to format the *actual* value when `verify`ing the (in order) call arguments of a method.

Mockito provides a overridable `describeTo` method within `ArcgumentMatcher<T>`s that enables me to format the *expected* value.
When mocking JRE classes like `DatagramPacket` using PowerMockito's `whenNew`, the *actual* value is not formatted the way I like.

In the following example I'm only interested if the address of the `DatagramPacket` was called in order. If not, I'd like to see the mismatching, actual value and not the default `toString()` name "`java.net.DatagramPacket@7546a399`".

My custom matcher is able to match only the `InetSocketAddress`.

### Example

**The custom matcher:**

```
static class IsDatagramForAddress extends ArgumentMatcher<DatagramPacket> {
    final InetSocketAddress addr;

    public IsDatagramForAddress(InetSocketAddress addr){
        this.addr = addr;
    }

    public boolean matches(Object dgp) {
        SocketAddress isa = ((DatagramPacket) dgp).getSocketAddress();
        boolean eq = isa.equals(addr);

        // System.out.println(dgp + ": " + isa + "< >" + addr + " == " + eq);

        return eq;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(addr == null ? null : addr.toString());
    }
}
```

**The test:**

```
private static DatagramPacket isDatagramForAddress(InetSocketAddress addr){
    return argThat(new IsDatagramForAddress(addr));
}

...

@Test
public void testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder() throws Exception {

    InOrder order = inOrder(sock);

    order.verify(sock).send(isDatagramForAddress(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.2", 100)));
    order.verify(sock).send(isDatagramForAddress(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.1", 100)));
}
```

**This is what I get:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure:
Verification in order failure
Wanted but not invoked:
datagramSocket.send(/8.8.8.1:100);
-> at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:95)
Wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction:
datagramSocket.send(
    java.net.DatagramPacket@7546a399
);
-> at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:90)

    at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:95)
    ...
```

**This is what I expect:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure:
Verification in order failure
Wanted but not invoked:
datagramSocket.send(/8.8.8.1:100);
-> at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:95)
Wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction:
datagramSocket.send(/8.8.8.2:100);
-> at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:90)

    at xxxx.XxxxTest.testSendIsCalledWithServersInOrder(XxxxTest.java:95)
    ...
```

### Question boiled down

How can I format/`toString()` the *actual* value?

Answer (score 3):

You could make your `ArgumentMatcher` store the last object that was passed to it, then include it in your `describeTo` method.  This might look something like this.

```
static class IsDatagramForAddress extends ArgumentMatcher<DatagramPacket> {
    final InetSocketAddress addr;
    DatagramPacket lastCompared;

    public IsDatagramForAddress(InetSocketAddress addr){
        this.addr = addr;
    }

    public boolean matches(Object dgp) {
        if (dgp instanceof DatagramPacket) {
            lastCompared = (DatagramPacket) dgp;
            SocketAddress isa = lastCompared.getSocketAddress();
            return isa.equals(addr);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(addr == null ? null : addr.toString());
        if (lastCompared != null) {
            description.appendText("Last socket address was " + lastCompared.getSocketAddress());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting and pragmatic approach. +1 for that. But you do not get a check because I was hoping there's a out-of-box solution. The con of this is that developers not familar with this solution might be confused about the output and it might reporting facilities (which does not matter for me in this case though :).

Comment: So you'll only accept an answer to your question if the Mockito team develop a new feature for you?